# tomcat server isnt working after adding mysql dependency

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

tomcat server stopped working after adding mysql dependency to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.38</version>
</dependency>
```

here's the error

```
Aug 18, 2016 11:55:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 18, 2016 11:55:08 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:316)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:492)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:821)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:534)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

what can be the cause?

**UPD** Here is full error code:

```
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:messenger' did not find a matching property.
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jun 9 2016 13:55:50 UTC
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.36.0
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_102-b14
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Valeandor\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\apache-tomcat-8.0.36
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Valeandor\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\apache-tomcat-8.0.36
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Valeandor\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\endorsed
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Autodesk\Backburner\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;D:\Downloads\Software\eclipse-jee-neon-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1131 ms
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/messenger]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/messenger]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@6c51f0bb]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4958)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5088)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@3be1d941]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:699)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:137)
    ... 13 more

Aug 19, 2016 12:28:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 6 more

Aug 19, 2016 12:28:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 11 more

Aug 19, 2016 12:28:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:316)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:492)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:821)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:534)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

Aug 19, 2016 12:28:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 19, 2016 12:28:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:316)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:492)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:821)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:534)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

Comment: show error which is thrown before shutting down

Comment: @MGorgon "Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start." thats the error I get after I press start server

Comment: I bet there is another exception in server logs

Comment: below this exception trace it would says caused by, post that here

Comment: @Isiva it says that the code is too long to post

Answer (score 1):

The most important line in the log is

```
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

This says, that the JAR file (which is actually a ZIP file with a different extension) is broken - perhaps due some connection problem during downloading it from maven central repository.

Delete the file from your local Maven repository and rebuild the project - Maven will download it again, this time hopefully without breaking it.